# What is the term/command "make-buff" when used in a script?

Tags: buffer, command-line-arguments, azure-powershell

I have a script given to me by a colleague, however it has a command in it that I cannot find any results on. Sample is below. Colleague is no longer available to ask.

```
#create a buffer in the log
  function make-buff($spot)
   {write-host "`n`n####################$spot##########################`n`n"}

make-buff "Script Start" 
$errormark = 0
```

The command is used in a PowerShell script.
Thanks in advance for any assistance.

I am just trying to determine what the command is and does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It(make buff) is a user defined non built in PowerShell command. These functions are used for creating buffers in logs or sending data(Basically it is a function).

In your script `make-buff` is used as dynamic variable initializing. ( Suppose a variable value depends on an execution of particular statement or previous statements value)

[image]

Here I used emo function as below:

```
 function emo($e)
 {write-host "$e"}
 emo "Rithwik Started"
```

[image]

So, now you clearly understand it is a user defined function,
So, basically it is a function it is called like below."

```
FunctionName argumnets
```